# symfony2 - Many to many relation / Form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm stuck with a Symfony2 problem involving a Many-To-Many relation : I've got a User entity, and a Project entity, linked with a Many-To-Many relation :

My User entity :

```
class User implements UserInterface
{

[...]

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_project",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection $projects
 */
protected $projects;
```

And my Project entity :

```
class Project
{

 [...]

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="projects")
 */
protected $users;
```

Symfony2 created the "link" table (called user_project), and then I inserted some rows. For example I have 2 Users (id = 1 / id = 2) and 2 Projects (id = 1 / id = 2).

In my table user_project I inserted the following rows :

1. 1 (user_id) - 1 (project_id)
2. 1 (user_id) - 2 (project_id)
3. 2 (user_id) - 1 (project_id)

So that User 1 is assigned to both projects 1 and 2, and User 2 is assigned to project 1 only.

My problem is that I don't know how to select Projects for a specified User. For example, I want to display (in my form) a select box with the projects assigned to my user. (For User 2, I only want to have Project 1. in my select box)

My form :

```
$builder->add('project', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'WebaccessBugtrackerBundle:Project',
        'property' => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function($er) use ($userManager) {

            $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('project')
            ->orderBy('project.name', 'ASC');

            $qb-> ????


            }
            return $qb;
        },
        'property' => 'name'));
```

I hope you understand what I'm saying and that you can help me :)

Thanks !

Comment: Show whole code of form type and action

Comment: Check my question, i had the same problem and i just solve it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173133/many-to-many-and-form-symfony2

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a form class for your User entity, simply add this to the buildForm() function:

```
$builder->add('projects')
```

and Symfony should guess that you want a choice list with the projects for this specific user.

More on this in the Symfony doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm gonna check this.

Comment: You're welcome. That's also assuming that you have used the app/console doctrine:generate:entities command on your bundle, to create the getters and setters that will automatically be used by the form class.