# Many-To-Many and form Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

## What i have

I have a database table **usuario** (user) and a table **perfil** (profile), connected with a **perfiles_usuario** (profiles_users) table. A many-to-many relationship. I can now succesfully retrieve the profiles from a user by doing: $perfiles = $usuario->getPerfiles();

```
/**
 *
 * @return Perfil[]
 */
function getPerfiles()
{
    $perfiles = $this->getPerfilesCollection()->toArray();
    return $perfiles;
}
```

## What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to make form where you can add one or more existing profiles from the **perfil** (profile) table. I would like to have a multiple select field and select the profiles for the user.

## What I tried to do

My form builder

```
class UsuarioType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder

            ->add('username', 'text', array('required' => false))

            ->add('perfiles', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'UsuarioBundle:Perfil',
                'em' => 'dynamic_em',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){ 

                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.nombre', 'ASC');

                }, 
                'required' => false
            ))

        ;
    }
```

My view

```
<div class="clearfix">
    {{ form_widget(formulario.perfiles, { 'attr': { 'class': 'select-perfiles', 'multiple':'' } }) }} 
</div>
```

My error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
Centro\UsuarioBundle\Entity\Usuario::setPerfiles() must be of the type array, 
object given, called in C:\....\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php 
on line 345 and defined in C:\....\src\Centro\UsuarioBundle\Entity\Usuario.php line 450
```

Usuario.php line 450

```
public function setPerfiles(array $perfiles) // line 450
{
    # Borra los perfiles que tiene el usuario
    $this->getPerfilesCollection()->clear();

    # Asigna los perfiles pasados por parámetro
    foreach ($perfiles as $perfil) {
        $this->addPerfil($perfil);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I think that the problem is in my user createAction:

```
$usuario = new Usuario();
$formulario = $this->crearCrearForm($usuario);
$formulario->handleRequest($request); <--------- ... at this line
```

And this is the Form Data

```
....
centro_extranetbundle_usuario[username]:test
centro_extranetbundle_usuario[perfiles]:9
centro_extranetbundle_usuario[perfiles]:4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much! here is the solution

```
/**
 * Devuelve una coleccion con los perfiles del usuario
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
function getPerfiles()
{

    $perfiles = $this->getPerfilesCollection(); # ->toArray(); I delete this
    return $perfiles;
}
```

Also i change

```
/**
 * Establece los perfiles del usuario a partir de un ArrayCollection de
 * perfiles
 * 
 * @param ArrayColection
 *
 * @return self
 */
public function setPerfiles(ArrayCollection $perfiles)
{
    // # Borra los perfiles que tiene el usuario
    // $this->getPerfilesCollection()->clear();

    // # Asigna los perfiles pasados por parámetro
    // foreach ($perfiles as $perfil) {
    //     $this->addPerfil($perfil);
    // }

    // return $this;

    $this->getPerfilesCollection()->clear();

    foreach($collection->toArray() as $perfil){
        $this->addPerfil($perfil);
    }
}
```

In the form builder i only add this line: 'multiple' => true,

```
->add('perfiles', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'UsuarioBundle:Perfil',
            'multiple' => true, <----------------------
            'em' => 'dynamic_em',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){

                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.nombre', 'ASC');

            }, 
            'required' => false
        ))
```

Comment: great that I could help you! Just one more suggestion: Change ArrayCollection to Collection (setPerfiles parameter instance). The reason is: sometimes a setter is called with a Parameter of type PersistantCollection or Proxy__. If you just ask for Collection interface is implemented, it will work, otherwise your app will crash.

Answer (score 1):

First problem: setPerfiles' parameter instance must be of Type collection (Doctrine Interface)
Second problem: perfiles is a collection, so you need the collection type in the form and a FormType for Perfiles.

Comment: I have read Symfony Docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html but i don't know how to get the profiles list for the multiple select field "Perfil" (profile)